# Fibonacci Calls

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, recursion, recursive-algorithms

The ’fib’ function returns the $n^{th}$
Fibonacci number if called using ’$fib(n)$’
Suppose calling ’$fib(n)$’ requires G(n)
calls to the ’fib’ function in total, because of recursion Prove that
$G(n) = G(n − 1) + G(n − 2) + 1$

Workings:

It would take $G(n-1)$ calls to call $fib(n-1)$ Fibonacci number and $G(n-2)$ calls for $fib(n-2)$ Fibonacci number and then 1 more call (FOR SOME REASON). Summing these up gives $G(n)$.

Is my thinking correct and what would the 1 call be for.

Comment: I mean, I think the $1$ they are looking for is the initial call of fib ( like, you call fib(n) which falls fib(n-1) and fib(n-2) ), but this question is really not well defined, since there are lots of non-recursive ways to implement the fib function.

Comment: @Callus Ok I see, that does make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The +1 'call' is the *addition* itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a programming question than a math one.

But what does the fib function really does ? it adds up two numbers.

So when you call fib(n), it computes fib(n-1), fib(n-2) and then add them up.

Maybe you can try and pseudo code fib() to get a better grasp of it, good luck =)

EDIT : As a side note, fib sequence is a traditional but very poor first example when you learn about recursive functions simply because there's betters ways to compute fib numbers. If you want to get a better example, look at "flood fill" algorithms.